# Display headers according to the data source property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, webforms

I use grid view in my project to display data.

I display to properties:

```
<asp:GridView ItemType="WebUI.FeatureInfoArea.FeatureDesc" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="gvFeatList" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Item.Title %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Item.Tip %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here how I bind to data source:

```
FeaturesDesc result = getData();

gvFeatList.DataSource = result.featureDesc;
gvFeatList.DataBind();
```

And here is FeaturesDesc class:

```
public class FeaturesDesc
{
    public List<FeatureDesc> featureDesc { get; set; }
}

public class FeatureDesc
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Tip { get; set; }
    public string UID { get; set; }
}
```

When columns is created on browser the data is displayed in rows, but headers of the columns are empty.

I know that I can use `TextHeader` attribute in `TemplateField` but I want that column header to be displayd dynamically according to `FeatureDesc` class property.

How can I make display column's header dynamically?

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns indicate whether bound fields are automatically created for each field in the data source.
AutoGenerateColumns="false" means creating **custom columns** and you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection to get the name of a property as seen here: [Get string name of property using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661824/get-string-name-of-property-using-reflection). It uses a method for extracting the name of a Property.

```
string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
{
    return (propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
}
```

And then use it like this like my answer in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842966/how-to-make-header-text-to-be-displayed-dynamically-in-templatefield).

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = GetPropertyName(() => featureDesc[0].Title);
```

You can also get a single object from the List and use `nameof`

```
var feature = featureDesc[0];

GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = nameof(feature.Tip);
```